# ActionBarSherlock overlay

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, overlay

I am using ActionBarSherlock in my applicaton and also SlideDrawer component on the bottom of the screen. Is somehow possible to overlay the action bar with the opened SlideDrawer? My problem is that the SlideDrawer is always only under the action bar. I need to cover the bar. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: put some code that you tried

Comment: I only setup the overlay tag to my styles.xml like this: <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>. Then I am able at least to put the slideDrawer under the action bar. But I want the SlideDrawer over the action bar.